# My grep for a process returns multiple strings with similar name

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, pattern-matching

I have a script that checks processes on our Linux servers.

An example would be we have a component named `ebond-dbreader-bbg` on server 1 and also a component named `ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt` on server 1.

When we run the following command, it returns a count 2 when it should be a count of 1 but it is getting confused as `bond-dbreader-bbg` is inside the name `ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt`.

Script minus the variables:

```
ps -ef | grep ebond-dbreader-bbg | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l
```

The output I get is 2

This is because if you do a

```
ps -ef | grep ebond-dbreader-bbg
```

you get two processes but one has a different name, see below:

```
[ebondgen@ebondfm1i20 bin]$ ps -ef | grep ebond-dbreader-bbg | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l
2


[ebondgen@ebondfm1i20 bin]$ ps -ef | grep ebond-dbreader-bbg
ebond    127056      1  2 00:15 ?        00:25:14 /opt/java1.8/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Dprogram.name=ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt -Dlog4j.configuration=file:resource/log4j.xml -Dproperty.file=resource/dbr.properties -DzooKeeperHosts=ebond-zookeeper1-uat.zit.commerzbank.com:2181 -DapplicationId=ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt-0 -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=1000K -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -Xloggc:/var/eBondTS/log/ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt.gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/eBondTS/log/ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt.hprof -cp :/opt/eBondTS/ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt/20191114135302_01000040/resource:/opt/eBondTS/ebond-dbreader-bbg-cbrt/20191114135302_01000040/lib/* -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=13075 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/jmxWrite.access -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/ldap.conf -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=LdapSSLNoVerify -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/eBondTS/serverkey/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=T55EJqVOdPLyVdnYpLMV -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=T55EJqVOdPLyVdnYpLMV -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.debug=true -Dbuild.number=1.0.40-01000040 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0 com.drkw.dbreader.DbReader


ebond    127572      1  2 00:15 ?        00:25:39 /opt/java1.8/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Dprogram.name=ebond-dbreader-bbg -Dlog4j.configuration=file:resource/log4j.xml -Dproperty.file=resource/dbr.properties -DzooKeeperHosts=ebond-zookeeper1-uat.zit.commerzbank.com:2181 -DapplicationId=ebond-dbreader-bbg-0 -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=1000K -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -Xloggc:/var/eBondTS/log/ebond-dbreader-bbg.gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/eBondTS/log/ebond-dbreader-bbg.hprof -cp :/opt/eBondTS/ebond-dbreader-bbg/20191114135312_01000040/resource:/opt/eBondTS/ebond-dbreader-bbg/20191114135312_01000040/lib/* -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=13074 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/jmxWrite.access -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/ldap.conf -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=LdapSSLNoVerify -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/eBondTS/serverkey/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=T55EJqVOdPLyVdnYpLMV -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/eBondTS/ebond-certificates/current/resource/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=T55EJqVOdPLyVdnYpLMV -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.debug=true -Dbuild.number=1.0.40-01000040 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0 com.drkw.dbreader.DbReader
ebondgen 134027  91663  0 19:12 pts/5    00:00:00 grep ebond-dbreader-bbg
```

I need this command

```
ps -ef | grep ebond-dbreader-bbg | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l
```

to return just 1 and not 2 as two is incorrect, does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Script with the variables

```
#!/bin/bash
outputDir=/tmp
touch $outputDir/checkOutput.txt

currentServerRole=$(/opt/eBondTS/ebond-server-scripts/current/bin/getServerRole.sh)
excludedComponents=('ebond-devops-scripts' 'ebond-checksum-validator' 'ebond-platform-webtool' 'ebond-deployment-guineapigone' 'ebond-deployment-guineapigtwo' 'ebond-deployment-guineapigthree' 'ebond-declarative-release' 'ebond-rhl-installer' 'ebond-web-broker' 'ebond-curvesubscriber' 'ebond-ampsperformancepublisher' 'ebond-ampsperformancesubscriber' 'ebond-diva-latencycheck' 'ebond-gal-latencycheck' 'ebond-neonpricerec-all' 'ebond-neonpricerec-banks' 'ebond-neonpricerec-chf' 'ebond-neonpricerec-covered' 'ebond-neonpricerec-credit' 'ebond-neonpricerec-derivatives' 'ebond-neonpricerec-emlm1' 'ebond-neonpricerec-emlm2' 'ebond-neonpricerec-other' 'ebond-neonpricerec-rates' 'ebond-neonpricerec-strips' 'ebond-neonpricerec-ust' 'razor-diva-test' 'ebond-reconcile-tool-tp-icap' 'ebond-reconcile-tool-bgc' 'ebond-reconcile-tool-tradition' 'ebond-zookeeper' 'ebond-ebond2bbg-reconciler' 'ebond-overnight-rates-subscriber' 'ebond-curvesubscriber' 'ebond-instrumentstatic-subscriber' 'ebond-userstatic-subscriber' 'ebond-web-broker')
ebond_components=$(grep runInServerRoles /opt/eBondTS/ebond*/current/etc/deployment.properties| awk -F'/' '{print $4}')
razor_components=$(grep -s runInServerRoles /opt/eBondTS/razor*/current/etc/deployment.properties| awk -F'/' '{print $4}')
all_components=$(echo ${ebond_components} ${razor_components})
echo "Id,ComponentName,CellName,ConfiguredYmlValue,BoxRunLevel,ExpectedToRun,CurrentProcessCount,CheckStatus" >> $outputDir/finalOutput.txt

for componentName in $all_components
do
expectedToRunIn=$(grep -s runInServerRoles  /opt/eBondTS/$componentName/current/etc/deployment.properties | sed 's,runInServerRoles=,,')
configuration=$(grep -s configuration  /opt/eBondTS/$componentName/current/etc/deployment.properties| sed 's,configuration=,,')
pkgType=$(grep -s packageType /opt/eBondTS/$componentName/current/etc/deployment.properties | sed 's,packageType=,,')
cellName=$(grep -s cellTeamName  /opt/eBondTS/$componentName/current/etc/deployment.properties| sed 's,cellTeamName=,,')
checkStatus="NOT-OK-CantCheck!!!!"

expectedCount="No"
if [ "$currentServerRole" == "$expectedToRunIn" ]; then
    expectedCount="Yes"
fi
if [ "$expectedToRunIn" == "all" ]; then
    expectedCount="Yes"
fi
if [[ pkgType = java ]]; then
        processes=$(ps -ef | grep "=$componentName " | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l)
else
        processes=$(ps -ef | grep $componentName | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l)
fi
```

Comment: can u remove the image and copy-paste the same as text...

Comment: Did you try "ebond-dbreader-bbg " with the space on the end and inside double quotes?

Comment: Have you tried using `pgrep`?

Comment: ^ `pgrep -c ebond-dbreader-bbg` would do what you want

Comment: Hi guys, this is my first time ever posting a question and i want to thank everyone for the extremely helpful answers and edits to my question. I have just added an update of the script with the variables. As i am struggling to incorporate your answers into the scrip with variables. @bu5hman if you have a look above it looks like we already use a space at the end inside the quotes yet still getting the issue.

Comment: @Valentin Bajrami i tried this but get an error "pgrep: invalid option -- 'c'" Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Hi made the following change to the script below please compare it to the one above, after the second grep i added speech marsk and a gap at the end inside the speech marks and this seems to have changed the return to 1 which looks correct, but im not sure if its a correct change or i have messed it up.
```
if [[ pkgType = java ]]; then
        processes=$(ps -ef | grep "=$componentName " | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l)
else
        processes=$(ps -ef | grep "$componentName " | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l)
fi

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
ps -ef | grep '[e]bond-dbreader-bbg ' | wc -l
```

You don't need `grep -v grep` with that solution.

Comment: The `[e]bond...` is a nice trick. The `wc -l` there is probably not needed as `grep` provides the `-c` flag to do the counting itself

Comment: Thank you so much, when i use that exact string on my linux server only a count of 1 is returned, however when i tried to incorporate it into my bash script it made no difference, maybe i did it wrong. I have just updated the question with the bash script with variables, are you able to tell how i can incorporate your suggestion into  --processes=$(ps -ef | grep "=$componentName " | grep -v grep| grep -Ev " pts/[0-9]{1,4}" |wc -l) -- thanks!

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk any update?

Comment: No. Your script is completely unreadable to me. You should provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).